# Flask_SQLAlchemy, db.create_all() is unable to "see" my tables when imported though a service class

Tags: python, sqlite, model-view-controller, flask-sqlalchemy

The intent: Refactor my code into MVC (this is just the model/database part), and have the server create the database with tables on first run if the database or tables does not exist.
This works when using a "flat" file with all the classes and functions defined in that file, but after moving out the functions into a service class and the models into their own folder with model classes, the `db.create_all()` function does not seem to be able to detect the table class correctly any more.

**Example structure**, *(minimum viable problem):*

**server.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.sqlite'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def main():
    # Intentionally moved into the main() function to prevent import loops
    from services.users import UserService
    users = UserService(db)
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**services\users.py**

```py
# Class used to access users data using a session

from models.users import Users


class UserService:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def get_all(self):
        return self.db.session.query(Users).all()

    def get(self, uid):
        return self.db.session.query(Users).get(uid)

    def add(self, json):
        user = Users(email=json['email'], password=json['password'])

        self.db.session.add(user)
        self.db.session.commit()

        return user
```

**models\users.py**

```py
# The actual model

from server import db


class Users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text)
    password = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Result: The database is created, but it is just an empty file with no tables inside of it.
I have also tried placing the `db.create_all()` inside the service class `def __init__(self, db)` (grasping at straws here), both as a self reference and as an argument reference. Neither have worked.

I am sure it is something obvious I am missing, but I have boiled down my project to just the bare minimum and still fail to see why it is not working - so I have to ask. How can I get the `db.create_all()` to detect my table classes correctly and actually create the required tables, while using this code structure (or something similar, in case I have misunderstood MVC)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `server.py` is executed twice

- when it's imported in `models/users.py`
- when `server.py` is called to run the app

Each execution generates a new `db` instance.  The `db` imported by the model file adds the models to its `metadata`, the `db` created when the app is run has empty metadata.

You can confirm this by printing `id(db)` and `db.metadata.tables` at the end of `models/users.py` and just before the call to `db.create_all()` in the `main` function.

You need to structure your code so that only one `db` gets created.  For example, you could move the app configuration and creation code into its own module, `mkapp.py` (feel free to come up with a better name):

**mkapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.sqlite'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And in `server.py` do

```
from mkapp import app, db
```

and in `models/users.py` do

```
from mkapp import db
```

As a bonus, this should also remove the import cycle.

---

I don't use flask much, so this solution can probably be improved on.  For example, having a function create `app` and `db` and memoise the results might be better than creating them in top-level module code.

Comment: That was right on the money, both for the db problem and the import cycle loop!